# Как пишется слово эко(?)промышленный парк?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис, сложные-слова

Знаю, что в сложных словах эко- слитно пишется. Но вдруг это какой-нибудь термин особый? В статьях на "КиберЛенинке" видела с дефисом. И вдогонку: эко(?)индустриальный парк, эко(?)технопарк, агро(?)эко(?)индустриальный парк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно:  эко индустриальный парк, но: экотехнопарк(одно слово).

Правило таково.

§ 153. Недопустимо слитное или дефисное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, если вторая часть содержит пробел, т. е. представляет собой сочетание слов. В этих случаях слитные или дефисные написания, рекомендуемые основными правилами, должны заменяться раздельными. Например, следует писать: **лже доктор наук, псевдо произведение искусства, теле круглый стол, мини стиральная машина; экс Советский Союз, псевдо Ван Гог, пол рабочего дня, пол столовой ложки, пол Московской области; то же в парных конструкциях с полу: полудеревни — полу дачные посёлки, полусанаторий — полу дом отдыха, полупародия — полу литературный фельетон, полуясли — полу детский сад** (в таких конструкциях заменяется также знак дефиса знаком тире по правилу [§ 154](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp.php).

Примечание. Следование основным правилам дало бы написания «телекруглый стол», «полрабочего дня» и т. д., а с учетом корректирующего правила § 151 — к написанию «псевдо-Ван Гог». В них искаженно представлены смысловые отношения между частями конструкции.

См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.

Comment: Без контекста не понятно, должно ли быть (эко [промышленный парк]), или ([экологический и промышленный] парк), или ([экологической промышленности] парк). Иначе говоря, «эко» к словосочетанию или к промышленности относится?

Comment: Примеры предложений: 1. Эко-промышленные парки и имеющие схожие задачи промышленные объекты основаны на принципах промышленной экологии. 2. Агро-эко-индустриальный парк или площадка - стратегически важный объект для устойчивого развития. Есть ещё такое: Создание агро-ЭТП начинается с разработки основных стратегий эко-индустриальных парков, строительства инфраструктуры. (Сохранила авторские дефисы.)

Comment: Написание примера 2 может быть "перенесено" с английского языка: Agro-eco-industrial parks (?). Сохранять ли тогда дефисное написание?

Comment: @Ася, наверное все-таки так: агро-эко индустриальных парков. В правилах подобные случаи не описываются.

Comment: К тому же, эко - как первая часть сложных слов пишется слитно. В интернете встречаются разные написания. Но в интернете никто не проверяет тексты на грамотность.